# Installation of phonegap windows unsigned .appx freezes at 16%

Tags: windows, cordova, extjs, phonegap, appx

I've try to install a unsigned phonegap windows app in my w10 desktop but the installation freezes at 16%.

I precise that : this native windows app has been developed with "ExtJS" framework and has been built with "phonegap build" without any microsoft developer key at this time. The android and iOS apps work fine.

Would you know the reason of this issue ? Would you think that this could be related to the developer signing key missing ?

[You will find a screenshot of the installation interuption.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhBxh.png)

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Enzo.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with deployment on Windows 10 Phone, but it was OK on Android and iOS.
In my case, there were two issues.

1) Wrong architecture
  - I was building for the wrong architecture. Changing this allowed me to install correctly.

2) Retina.js
  - Once installed, the application would crash. The crash was because Retina.js was being used and Windows did not like it. I do not know why. I removed it, and it worked. So try removing JS libraries one at a time and see if it works for you.